# How to check if the field exists or not using ORM

Tags: mongodb, orm, mongoengine

I am using MongoDB as a database for my application. I am using ORM to perform CRUD operations. I want to check if the field is existing in the record or not. By raw Mongo queries, I can achieve this by using the "$exists" method. Can someone suggest me how can we achieve this through ORM?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe by using `filter` and below query, you can find the fields which do not exist.
`Collection.objects.filter(field__ne=None)`